# invoke zsh, having it run a command, and then enter interactive mode instead of exiting

Tags: zsh

i'd like to start zsh similar to

```
zsh -c 'my_prog option1 option2'
```

but instead of exiting after running that command, leaving me at the propt of the invoked zsh (not wherever it is being called from).  one particular use-case for this is in screenrc files, you could do something like:

```
screen -t my_prog 0 zsh -c 'my_prog opt1 opt2'
```

and after running that command you're left with a shell there instead of it closing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not that I would advise doing this.

```
(sirius)~: zsh -c 'print hello; zsh -i'
hello
(sirius)~: echo $SHLVL
2
```

There are other tricks you can play with screen and using the `$STY` variable.

If you want something run from zsh with individual screens, you can check the $STY variable within your .zshrc or .zlogin.  It is in the format `<PID>.<TTY>.<HOSTNAME>`.

```
if [[ -n $STY ]] then
  if [[ -f ~/.zsh-$STY[(ws:.:)2] ]] then
    . ~/.zsh-$STY[(ws:.:)2]
  fi
fi
```

If in screen, and if `~/.zsh-<TTY>` (from the $STY variable) exists, source that, then continue on your merry way.  You can also set an environment variable before calling the interactive shell.

```
> FOO=bar zsh -i
> env | grep FOO
FOO=bar

> RUNTHISCOMMAND=/path/to/script zsh -i
.zshrc:
if [[ -n $RUNTHISCOMMAND ]] then
   $RUNTHISCOMMAND
fi
```

Add those checks into your .zshrc/.zlogin.

Comment: kudos for teaching me about SHLVL

Comment: i was hoping to avoid the nested shell, but oh well.

Answer (score 17):

I found a solution that works without an extra shell [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2005/msg00599.html). Add:

```
if [[ $1 == eval ]]
then
    "$@"
set --
fi
```

to .zshrc, then call zsh with

```
zsh -is eval 'your shell command here'
```

Really great for starting up lots of shells at once.

Comment: It should be noted that this is best placed at the very end of the `.zshrc`. I had some plugins that had automatically placed their setup code in `.zshrc` after the eval hook. Typically I'm running infinite processes like `npm start` in the eval hook. When killing them with `CTRL + C` I was always surprised that some zsh plugins had stopped working. Of course the reason is that the `.zshrc` only got evaluated up to the `$@`.

Answer (score 11):

What about appending `; exec zsh` to the command? That way there's only one shell left at the end.

Comment: You actually don't need the exec if you `; zsh -i`, it does that for you already.

Comment: The weird thing when I `source` my `zsh` after the change my terminal goes into like an infinite loop however if I use `; exec zsh {command that I want to run} ;`checked to see if there was any broken code further up or any potential code that would cause this to happen but everything above the evaluation was 100s :/

Answer (score 8):

I have `eval "$RUN"` at the end of my `.zshrc`. I can now run commands without the extra shell, with:

```
RUN='my_prog opt1 opt2' zsh
```

Comment: This seems a weird kludge - but it works so well!

Comment: This can get problematic if your shell can spawn other shells. So eg. if I use RUN=nvim zsh and then inside the spawned vim I open the embedded terminal suddenly I have vim inside vim.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias uce='USE_CUSTOM_ENV=1 zsh'
if [[ "${USE_CUSTOM_ENV}" == "1" ]]; then
        alias a='stuff I need in this context'
        alias x='exit'
        ...

        PROMPT="${PROMPT}%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[red]%}[CUSTOM_ENV] %{$reset_color%}"
        my_prog option1 option2
fi
```

Upon invoking `uce` on the command line a new interactive subshell is invoked where `my_prog` is executed. This approach has the advantage of giving me a custom environment (with aliases, functions, envvars, etc.) for the specific context.