# Is there a way to launch a command within a proper zsh shell?

Tags: zsh, tmux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [invoke zsh, having it run a command, and then enter interactive mode instead of exiting](https://superuser.com/questions/91881/invoke-zsh-having-it-run-a-command-and-then-enter-interactive-mode-instead-of-e)

I'm not really clear with my question here, let me rephrase it :

I've setup a launch_workspace.sh to launch directly tmux with 5 different commands loaded.
Here is my current content :

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s scube -n 'vim' "vim"

tmux new-window -t scube:2 -n 'server' "$SHELL -c 'script/rails server'"
tmux new-window -t scube:3 -n 'yard' "$SHELL -c 'bundle exec yard server --gems'"
tmux new-window -t scube:4 -n 'spork' "$SHELL -c 'bundle exec guard'"
tmux new-window -t scube:5 -n 'autotest' "$SHELL -c 'bundle exec autotest'"
tmux new-window -t scube:5 -n 'shell' "$SHELL"

tmux select-window -t scube:1
tmux -2 attach-session -t scube
```

Problem is : my zsh ($SHELL beeing zsh) launches said commands, but when I Ctrl+C any of these, it closes the full zsh (hence my tmux window) and not just return to a proper zsh prompt.

Is there a way to have said behavior, to launch zsh with a command and return to a zsh prompt when the command fails ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake, it looks like this has already been answered there : [invoke zsh, having it run a command, and then enter interactive mode instead of exiting](https://superuser.com/questions/91881/invoke-zsh-having-it-run-a-command-and-then-enter-interactive-mode-instead-of-e)