# Invoke zsh, then *source* another file (while entering interactive mode)

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh

This question is of course related, but different to [the one about *executing* a command](https://superuser.com/questions/91881/invoke-zsh-having-it-run-a-command-and-then-enter-interactive-mode-instead-of).

That questions’ solutions involve either starting a subshell – which isn’t possible due to the requirement of sourcing instead of executing – or modifying your `~/.zshrc`, which isn’t possible if you want to distribute a script that does it. (Or rather modifying the user’s config files is a thing you just don’t do)

The problem is that with zsh there is no `--init-file` parameter like bash has (the first time ever i saw bash having a feature that zsh hasn’t)

I’ll provide an answer with my question, but it’s reeeaaallly ugly, and I hope someone knows a trick to circumvent it!

Comment: If you are distributing a script, can't you just add the commands to the top of the script (or at least a `source` command to source the appropriate file). I think I'm missing the rationale for the question.

Comment: No, the script should be sourced from inside a shell that has some environment variables set, after the user’s rc files have been sourced. all that automatically.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `modules` (http://modules.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: Wow, that would be total overkill :) thanks though! Well, in fact I would like a simpler solution than the one I provided below, not a more complicated one…

Comment: To update an old question, I'm looking for the same thing. My use case is to use an iTerm profile to launch a particular environment (simply, setting `$GOPATH` and `cd`ing there). Frankly, I'm very surprised this doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) tells us that there is a `$ZDOTDIR`, which makes a very ugly solution possible:

1. `/distdir/my-cmd`:

   Use shell-specific ways to replace init files or fail hopelessly.

   ```
   case $(basename $SHELL) in
       zsh)  OLD_ZDOTDIR="$ZDOTDIR" ZDOTDIR="/distdir" zsh -i ;;
       bash) bash --init-file "/distdir/.zshrc" -i ;;
       *)    echo "Unrecognized shell $SHELL"; exit 1 ;;
   esac
   ```
2. `/distdir/.zshrc`:

   Named `.zshrc`, as the names are hardcoded in zsh, but bash can be passed a arbitrarily named file via `--init-file`. It would also be possible to name this e.g. `our_stuff.sh`, and create a `.zshrc` which contains just `. ./our_stuff.sh`.

   As we don’t actually want to *replace* the init files, but to append another, we have to painstakingly recreate the builtin sequence of sourcing them.

   ```
   # ignore profile, login & logout rc files, as we want no login shells
   case $(basename $SHELL) in
       zsh)
           test -f "$OLD_ZDOTDIR/.zshenv" && . "$OLD_ZDOTDIR/.zshenv"
           test -f "$OLD_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc"  && . "$OLD_ZDOTDIR/.zshrc"
           ;;
       bash)
           test -f ~/.bashrc        && source ~/.bashrc
           test -f /etc/bash.bashrc && source /etc/bash.bashrc
           ;;
   esac

   do_our_stuff!

   PS1="myenv! $PS1" #tell the user he’s in a modified shell
   ```

Comment: Part of my confusion as to what your ultimate goal is: why are you sourcing a `.zshrc` file when you are starting an instance of `bash`?

Comment: To answer the last question, a login `bash` shell (interactive or not) always executes `/etc/profile` if it exists. I think that is the only global startup file for `bash` (something like `/etc/bashrc` may be provided by your OS distribution and sourced from a provided default `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`, but `bash` itself does not look for it).

Comment: @chepner: I already answered your comment in the question at the beginning of the explanation for the `.zshrc` file. I want the same file to be sourced in bash, if the user uses bash, and in zsh if he uses zsh. Bash accepts an `--init-file`, zsh just a `$ZDOTDIR`, in which it searches for specific, hard-coded filenames. So I gave the file one of those hard-coded names, because bash doesn’t care how it’s named. Got it? :)

Comment: About the last question: Thanks! I’ll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is still absent in zsh, but there's [zshi](https://github.com/romkatv/zshi), a small script that achieves what you want. Quoting its README:

> Usage: `zshi <init-file> [zsh-flag]...`
>
> The same as plain `zsh [zsh-flag]...` except that an additional <init-file> gets sourced after all standard Zsh startup files.