# Start zsh with a prompt specified on the command line

Tags: command-line, zsh

Is it possible to start an interactive zsh session with a specific prompt without modifying a configuration file?

I tried things like that:

```
zsh -c 'autoload -U prompt; prompt adam1; zsh -i'
```

But that obviously doesn't work as the ending `zsh -i` starts a fresh new interactive session.

A solution to this may be the use of an option telling zsh to load a specific configuration file (again, without modifying any existing default configuration file such as `~/.zshrc`), something like:

```
zsh -i --configuration=~/path/to/foo.zshrc
```

But I don't know and can't find such an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke zsh, then \*source\* another file (while entering interactive mode)](http://superuser.com/questions/591439/invoke-zsh-then-source-another-file-while-entering-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this question: [Invoke zsh, then *source* another file (while entering interactive mode)](https://superuser.com/questions/591439/invoke-zsh-then-source-another-file-while-entering-interactive-mode)

The solution is to write the commands I want to run in a `.zshrc` file in any folder I want, for example:

`~/path/to/foo/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz prompt
prompt adam1
```

And start zsh with a modified `ZDOTDIR` environment variable:

```
ZDOTDIR=~/path/to/foo zsh
```

<sub>I flagged my question as duplicate of the one I linked and upvoted the question and it's answer, sorry for the noise.</sub>